# Two Javascript arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

There is a product page in the store. The goods are gift card codes. Each has its own price. Cards are bought using a form with buttons for card denominations (each has its own price), which is almost completely unrelated to the product page (the form is in a pop-up, called by clicking on the button), and product cards appeared as a bonus, they were not originally planned. But since there is such a thing, it is necessary to adjust it. The essence of the task is that when you click on the popup call in the form, the button of the required card denomination is clicked. So that the parameters in the form change accordingly. I thought to cling to the url of the product page (in the url there is something like nominal-4000). But I don’t know how to make a comparison so that part of this url is compared with an array of buttons that also have the same class (of type nominal-4000). Here's what I was able to do:

```
const popupBtn = document.querySelector('.popup-btn');

pb.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
   e.preventDefault();
   document.body.classList.add('popup-open');


   let nominal4000 =  document.querySelector('.nominal-4000');

   let field = 'nominal-4000';

   if(window.location.href.indexOf(field) > -1) {
      nominals.forEach(nominal => {
         nominal.classList.remove('active-nominal');
         if (nominal.classList.contains(field) ) {
            nominal4000.click();
            nominal4000.classList.add('active-nominal');
         }
      })
   }
```

Here I'm just looking for the button and the url part of the page by nominal-4000. Works. But there will be 10 total products, and therefore pages and, consequently, buttons. That is, an array is needed. And their comparison, or something else. I have not delved into such wilds of JS yet, I cannot understand what and how. Use for example an array with denominations (they are also part of the url):

```
var fields = [
  'nominal-3000',
  'nominal-4000',
  'nominal-5000'
];
```

Then an array with button classes, something like this -

```
var nominals = document.querySelectorAll(`${fields}`);
```

Here is a comparison of two arrays

```
let isFounded = fields.some( ai => nominals.includes(ai) );
```

But it doesn't all work together. Who fumbles in arrays, help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
const popupBtn = document.querySelector('.popup-btn');

popupBtn.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.body.classList.add('popup-open');

  var fields = [
    'nominal-3000',
    'nominal-4000',
    'nominal-5000'
  ];

  var nominals = document.querySelectorAll(`.${fields.join(', .')}`);

  fields.forEach(field => {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf(field) > -1) {
      nominals.forEach(nominal => {
        nominal.classList.remove('active-nominal');
        if (nominal.classList.contains(field) ) {
          nominal.click();
          nominal.classList.add('active-nominal');
        }
      })
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Code-only answer, without any explanation.